# how to find the flattest area or a polysurface in rhino? by scripting

Tags: python, rhino

Given a set of xyz points, I want to find clusters of points that have the smallest variation in the z value.  Basically how to find the flattest area of a collection of points.

Comment: Could you be more mathematically precise about what you mean? How big are the clusters, or how does cluster size factor in to the flatness calculation?

Comment: What I understood: from a set of `z` values (`x` and `y` don't seem to be relevant to the problem) you want to find the combination of three where `max(combination) - min(combination)` is the smallest?

Comment: The importance of x and y is that i need clusters of points, not just the max and min of z.  So a cluster would mean that a specific area of x,y (adjacent) points have a low difference in min(z) and max(z)